# What is the most efficient way to extract and process files from the link?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to browse all the links I need, but these links are redirecting me to the websites which have another links with pdf files, I have to open and process these pdfs. But I do not know what is the most efficient way to do it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
 
url = 'https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?reference=2014/0124(COD)&l=en'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("AM")):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-544465_EN.html
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-541655_EN.html
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-551891_EN.html
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-544465_EN.html
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-541655_EN.html
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-551891_EN.html
```

Answer (score 1):

For all links that you crawl from the main url, you need to do exactly the same as before (request, bs4, extract hrefs).

- Then check if href of link ends with ".pdf"
- If href is a relative path of the pdf file, use urllib to extract the domain from the website url and concatenate the domain and the pdf file name again

E. g.:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

domain = urlparse("https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-544465_EN.html").netloc
```

- Do another get request to retrieve the context of the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You've done it right. You just need a simple modification:

## Solution for this specific problem

You have done the hardest part. Just replace ".html" with ".pdf" and then download the file is a manner like this:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("AM")):
    page_url = str(link.get('href'))
    pdf_url = page_url.replace('.html', '.pdf')
    pdf_response = requests.get(url)
    with open('/blah_blah_blah/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

## What was the problem?

Dear friends, many websites have a dedicated webpage for any of their links. Usually it is so, for the sake of "SEO" purposes!
The good point is: "There is often a relation between the page link and the target file's link.

For example here we have:

```
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-544465_EN.html
```

And when we check that page we find that the url is:

```
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/EMPL-AM-544465_EN.pdf
```

So you just need to change the ".html" tail to ".pdf" and then go for a download.

## What to do if there is no relation?

Then you should do exactly what a human does. Open/Fetch the page and then extract the content link explicitly. After that you can download the target file.

## Do we have even harder situations?

Yes. Sometimes the website has AJAX and ... operations to get the link. In those cases I suggest trying to follow the behavior of the browser and to check if there exists a pattern between the link (usually an API) and the content.

But there exists even harder situations that you will use alternatives like "Selenium".